# CakePHP user forging sessions

Tags: session, cakephp

I'm experiencing a weird behavior in my cakePHP app. I have the follow in some kind of vote system:

```
$user_id = ($this->Session->check('User')) ? $this->Session->read('User.id') : 0;
$data = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'object_id' => $this->params['form']['object_id'],
    'datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);

$this->Votes->create();
$this->Votes->save($data);
```

As you can see, if `$_SESSION['User']` is not set, the `user_id` will be zero (0). Otherwise, it will be the user ID. User session is created when the user logs in.

This allows non-logged users to vote also, which is ok.

**The problem is...** Somehow a bunch of votes with `user_id != 0` (i.e. supposedly existent and logged members) was saved. When I checked for the user ID's, they don't exist on the users table.

It is like someone sent votes with random user ID's. ID's that don't even exist!

Important to note that:

- the user ID is not coming from any user input. It is read from the session;
- there is not relationship between votes and users. The tables are in two different and databases for this purpose they don't need any relationship

Does anyone know if I'm missing something here? Am I assuming things that are not right? How can someone forge an user ID, in this case an ID that does not exist?

Comment: i am pretty sure this is usually not possible. could it be that those users deleted their account?

Comment: Nop. users can't delete accounts. For now I have simply included a `SELECT` before saving the data to be sure that the user exists. But in a long term this is not very practical. I need to be sure that nobody is messing with the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

(Base on CakePHP 2.0.5, but it should apply to Cake 1.3.x as well)

First of all, how do you set the user's Session? What do you mean by `User session is created when the user logs in`?

If you're digging the `User.id` set by `AuthComponent`, it's actually `Auth.User` and `Auth.User.id`. You can do a `debug($this->Session->read())` to check if you have correctly mining the value from `Session`.

Usually, in my application, I use `AuthComponent` to get the logged in user.id. This is much reliable as this is set by Cake automatically if you use their built in `AuthComponent::login` method, and Cake will unset them once the user session expired (or logging out), and thus you can rely on it to check if a user has logged in or not.

I would suggest the following thou:

```
$user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$data = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'object_id' => $this->params['form']['object_id'],
    'datetime' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())
);

$this->Votes->create();
$this->Votes->save($data);
```

And your `$user_id` will either be a digit, or `NULL`, if there is no valid user session.

**Read more:**

- [AuthComponent::user method (Cake 1.3)](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1255/AuthComponent-Methods#user-1264)
- [AuthComponent::user method (Cake 2.0)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3auser)

Cheers

Comment: I'm using an old cakePHP release (1.2). Migration to 1.3, in my case, revealed too many errors/warnings that it was postponed. I'm not using AuthComponent. Session is created using Session->write() when the user authenticates. Thanks for the reply though. It reminded me that I must migrate to a new release asap.

Comment: Ah all right. I think it *might be a problem in 1.2. You should migrate them asap. 2.1 is coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was an error on the sign-up process. There was a step where new users could go back to change/add info before hit the final "OK".

By mistake, a session with the future (but not yet created) user ID was being set. At this point, if this user tried to vote, he would have a valid session but of a user that does not exist.